# How to find an unknown angle in a triangle with many sections?

Tags: trigonometry

I’m not doing so well with trigonometry! I once again would really appreciate some help with this question. I have been given a number of different angles in this triangle but I can’t figure out how to solve for the specific angle. [image: Q7]

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with trigonometry since you are only working with angles in triangles and you need not know anything about the lengths of the line segments here.  Consider labeling sizes of angles that you can determine using the fact that triangles have a sum of interior angles of $180^\circ$.

Comment: I agree with Andrew. Seems like you only need to apply that rule to all the (four?) triangles in the picture.

Comment: I would recommend you find all the angles you can. It then may become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha = \arctan{\frac{\overline{DF}}{\overline{FE}}} = \arctan{\frac{\overline{AF}\tan{10°}}{\overline{FB}\tan{40°}}} = \arctan{\frac{\tan{30°}\tan{10°}}{\tan{40°}}} = 6.92°$ (since $\angle{AFB}=90°$)